# Sumar campos de una tabla

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, select, insert

Muy buenas!!

Necesito ayuda con una consulta de SQL en phpmyadmin pues me estoy volviendo loco. El caso es que tengo esta tabla llamada "hc":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero, que se sumen los valores de los campos Alquimista, Artesano, Cocinero, Archivo, Fundición, Contable y Luchador (todos campos numéricos). El caso es que utilizo el siguiente código para que me muestre una columna llamada "Suma":

select *, (`Alquimista`+`Artesano`+`Cocinero`+`Archivo`+`Fundición`+`Contable`+`Luchador`) as suma from hc

Esto funciona perfectamente, pero quiero que la columna que me cree sea permanente, y que se guarde en la columna "Total" de la tabla. Así que para ello introduzco el siguiente cógido:

insert into hc.Total
select *, (`Alquimista`+`Artesano`+`Cocinero`+`Archivo`+`Fundición`+`Contable`+`Luchador`) as Total from hc

El caso es que me da problemas de permisos y mi proveedor dice que es algo del código, que no tiene que ver con los permisos pues ellos pueden realizar un INSERT en la tabla.

¿Alguien me puede decir qué estoy haciendo mal? Este es uno de los códigos que he probado, realizando modificaciones sobre el mismo me da otro tipo de errores.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Podrías incluir el error que te da el insert?

Comment: Hola, el error es #1142 - INSERT comando negado para usuario: 'sergiom51'@'10.3.8.86' para tabla 'Total', pero mi proveedor indica que la sintaxis del comando insert es insert into your_table (c1, c2, ...) select c1, c2, ... from your_table where id = 1, y que el código está mal escrito, de ahñí que os solicite ayuda. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Insert inserta una fila en la tabla, no inserta un dato en un campo... No, no esta bien

Update sirve para actualizar un campo de una fila... vos queres actualizar un valor en una fila, no insertar...

lo que te dice tu proveedor es correcto para la sintaxis de tu insert (tu insert para colmo esta mal), pero ahora, imaginate que queres insert usando insert, como sabe en que fila guardar esos datos que estas sumando?

Lo que vos queres se hace asi:

```
update hc 
set Total = (Alquimista+Artesano+Cocinero+Archivo+Fundición+Contable+Luchador)
```

Igual, no entiendo para que querrias un campo que guarde el total. Cada vez que cambie uno de esos valores vas a tener que recalcular ese valor. Ya escribiste un trigger para eso?

Comment: Gracias, ha funcionado. Pero efectivamente, lo que quiero es que cada vez que se modifique un campo, se modifique el total. Podría hacer el update cada cierto tiempo, pero sería más eficiente no tener que hacerlo y actualizar el campo Total automáticamente.

Comment: @RetoImposible y por eso te pregunte si ibas a escribir un trigger para eso. No deberias calcular el total, en muy raros casos lo necesitas... y este no parece ser uno de esos.

Comment: Bueno, esto es algo personal, el total me sirve para ordenar a los participantes, son unos cuantos y así puedo acceder a ver sus datos más rápidamente. Pero no sé hacer un trigger para esto

Comment: @RetoImposible no se cuantos participantes tenes... pero salvo que hablemos de millones no creo que tengas problemas

Comment: Son 66, pero la cuestión es que no sé hacer un trigger

Comment: 66 para una base de datos es nada... y si no, te tocara estudiar triggers @RetoImposible

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso mismo estoy haciendo. Y muchas gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda!!!

Comment: @RetoImposible recorda leer el [tour] y aceptar las respuests que te sirven!!!!